# Number Lines. Visual Studio for 8

Tags: visual-studio

In the code editor in Visual Studio for Windows 8 Apps how can I enable line numbers?

For example instead of

```
this
is
my
code
```

to

```
1. this
2. is 
3. my
4. code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.On the menu bar, choose Tools, Options.

2.In the categories list on the left side of the Options window, expand the Text Editor node.

3.Expand the All Languages subfolder, and then choose General to set this option globally.

4.In the Display section, select the Line numbers check box.

[Microsoft Answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165340.aspx)